# How to reverse the order in which ListPlot plots multiple array of numbers?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am new to mathematica. I have been trying to plot a list of values. The list looks somewhat like this:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

What I want is to plot, $\{1,2\}$ (both these points) at $x =1$, and points $\{1,2,3\}$ at $x =2$, etc. I tried converting the list to a form $\{\{1,1,1\},\{2,2,2\},\{3,3\},\{4\}\}$ and list plotting, but this puts $\{1,2\}$ at $x = 3$, rather than $x = 1$. So if I can make `ListPlot` plot first values at $x = 3$ and go backwards from there my problem can be solved. But I could not find a way to specify the $x$ values for `ListPlot`.

Comment: Please consider adding the `ListPlot` you used to your question, so that people can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Add x-coordinates to each data point using [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) + [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html):

```
list2 = MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &] @ list
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
>  {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}},
>  {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[list2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotLegends -> InputForm /@ list]
```

[image]

You can also use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) + [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%27Tuples%60.html), or [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) + [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to construct `list2`:

```
list3 = MapIndexed[Tuples @* Reverse @* List] @ list;;

list4 = MapThread[Thread @* List] @ {Range @ Length @ list, list};

list2 == list3 == list4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach is to use `PadRight` to obtain a rectangular 4X3 array :

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
Transpose[PadRight[list, Automatic, {Null}]]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {Null, 3, 3}, {Null, Null, 4}}

and then `ListPlot` :

```
ListPlot[Transpose[ PadRight[list, Automatic, {Null}]] ]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `Missing[]` instead of `Null` would be preferable, even though any non numeric value works here.

Answer (score 1):

`Table` is OK.

```
n = 10;
list = Range[Range[2, n]]
Table[Table[{i, j}, {j, list[[i]]}], {i, 1, Length@list}]
ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[{a___, b_}] := {b - 1, #} & /@ {a, b}
```

```
f /@ {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} // ListPlot
```